# Is Apache-Tika library supports below android oreo devices?

Tags: java, android, mime-types, apache-tika

I am using Apche-tika library for Mimetype detection in android,

**Android => O: Greater than or equal to android version O:**

it is working fine in android version above Oreo.

Link : https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/file/package-summary

**Android < O:less than android version Oreo:**

but below oreo it is giving "NO SUCH METHOD" Exception because it is using nio file detection type .
is there any alternative library for Mimetype detection in below oreo devices (android api 26).

implementation 'org.apache.tika:tika-core:1.11' .  this is the library I am using.

Comment: What version of Java does your old Android implement? We'd need to know that to be able to advise what older version of Apache Tika (if any) to use

Comment: I am using java 8 version and Apche-tika 11 version. thanks in advance.

Comment: Update on this would help me in deciding to use Apache Tika library.

Comment: Still it is not working in below Oreo devices, above Oreo  it will work fine. you can use it for above O support.